# To Capture the Error in Sybase IQ SQL Execution using dbisqlc inside ksh shell Script

Tags: unix, ksh, sap-iq, isql, sybase-asa

I have a shell script as below through which I'm connecting Sybase IQ through dbisqlc.

I would like to capture if there Error is any Error occurs during the Script Execution. I coded like below. But eventhough if there is any failure in SQL Execution , the Return Count in always 0.

```
dbisqlc -c "uid=UID;pwd=PWD;eng=DEV;links=tcpip(host=XXXX;port=XXX)" -q   Query.sql  OutputDumpFile   
RC=`echo $?`
if [ $RC != 0 ]
then
    echo "ERROR: Error in DB Query Execution"
fi
```

Please help how to capture the SQL Error in UNIX for Sybase IQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this documentation](http://dcx.sap.com/1100/en/dbadmin_en11/dbisqlc-interactive-dbutilities.html), `dbisql` is recommended over `dbisqlc`:

> It is recommended that you use the Interactive SQL utility (accessed
>   by using the **dbisql** command or by choosing Start » Programs » SQL
>   Anywhere 11 » Interactive SQL) where possible because the **dbisqlc**
>   utility does not support all the features that Interactive SQL does

It goes on to say:

> Only the **dbisql** utility has the ability to provide exit codes from a
>   SQL script.

So based on that, it seems to me that `dbisqlc` does not convey information via exit codes.